# Nikon autofocus refocuses when using live view

Tags: nikon, live-view, nikon-d7100

I haven't used live view much, but need to use to for a self service "photo booth" for an event, where I am using the HDMI output so that guests are able to see the composition of the shot and pose.

I have the camera, a Nikon D7100, set to face focus mode. From the view on the screen it appears to work well and shows green rectangles around faces (which I believe means in focus).

However when the shutter button is pressed (either on the camera, or with remote control) the camera takes a second to refocus before taking the photo.

Is there any setting that can be changed to just use the focus currently seen in live view, and avoid the time penalty to refocus?

Edit:
I am using a Nikon d7100 with a AF-S Nikkor 35mm 1:1.8g prime, I don't have the final setup yet but tests have been done in a bright room (I do note that the live view won't continuously autofocus unless there is a certain brightness)

Comment: @chulster There is a [nikon-d7100] tag attached to the question.

Comment: Have you tried setting "shutter release priority" to 'release' instead of 'focus'? I don't know about the D7100, but many cameras have such an option buried in the menu somewhere.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what lens are you using? And what is the lighting like for your photobooth? Do you use continuous illumination, or a flash, or is there plenty of natural or existing lighting?

Comment: @scottb detail added to question.

Comment: @michael C there is a setting for shutter priority for both af-s and af-c but I don't think they affect live view.

Comment: Thanks for the added detail, it's helpful, but I was hoping to know _specifically_ is the lens a Nikon-branded lens, or a third party lens?

Comment: @scottbb sorry, didn't occur to me, it is the Nikon Lens, revised question.

Comment: To add further detail, this is what it looks like, I am triggering the camera with a remote ir shutter, and you can see where it refocuses, when it does refocus it looks and sounds like it is moving the aperture as well. If I set camera to manual focus the picture gets taken imediately as expected. https://photos.app.goo.gl/kbdupwYhFyD45koF8

Comment: @Hugoagogo Have you tried it in LV to see?

Comment: "... so that guests are able to see the composition of the shot and pose." Just curious why you decided this is necessary? Most photo booths (both the real ones that were actually *in a booth* and the present backdrop + subject activated camera + zany props) don't give the subjects a preview of themselves.

Comment: As far as that goes, most of them are prefocused with enough DoF to not need focusing before each shot. But then again, most also use off camera flashes in modifiers to insure there's enough light to allow a moderately narrow aperture.

Comment: Have you tried 'back button focus'? Then you can use different buttons for focusing and taking the shot.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the settings issue but you certainly can use manual mode. If your f stop gives you enough depth of field, you can just leave the focus and shoot to your hearts content from person to person.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the camera is set to focus on a half press of the shutter release.

You can override this by setting the Fn or AE-L/AF-L buttons as "AF-ON". In this case, according to page 253 and 256 of [the manual available here](http://download.nikonimglib.com/archive2/Wt74B00WmPdp01GF7sU080xUqy56/D7100_(En)03.pdf) :

> "Pressing the [Fn or AE-L/AF-L] button initiates autofocus.The
>   shutter-release button can not be used to focus."

This may not help if you have something else you want to assign to these buttons, in which case there's always - as jmPhotography suggests - manual focus.